# Angular: JSON data in template (avoid extra AJAX-call)

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

I am developing an AngularJS app, and I would like the initial JSON data for the $scope to be included in the first page load, rather than fetched after the fact via AJAX. The reasoning for this is that it would increase performance, but I haven't been able to find any best practice on how to do this, or even whether to do this at all.

My current idea is to add an inline `<script>`-tag at the bottom of the template, and include the data there, perhaps as a service definition that the controller can then inject and query for initial data. The data can be placed in the `<script>`-tag by the server side, where I have ASP.NET MVC which could render the data.

Should I be doing this some other way? Should I even be doing it at all, or should I just accept that my page will require an extra AJAX-call to populate it with data before it's ready?

Comment: Your approach is viable if you really want to resort to something like that. Nevertheless, I'm inclined to agree with Chandermani here.

Answer (score 1):

I believe extra AJAX call is absolutely fine. The performance benefits that you realize with embedded JSON in script is not worth the trouble if you consider the maintainability of your approach. This is a standard pattern with most of the AJAX enabled web apps. There may be other ways to improve performance such as server side caching and browser caching of response.